# Unable to pull data from Scratch Org using SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx

I have two scratch orgs, one has data(both on local and on remote) and other is empty. Then, I pushed the data from my first org to second one using `sfdx force:source:push` command. The data is available online(remotely) on the second org, but when I tried to pull data from the second org to the local folder it shows "No result found(that there is no difference b/w remote and local)".

Does anyone have any idea how can I sync my data?

Comment: You say you have two scratch orgs - are these orgs in completely separate Salesforce DX *projects*? Have you made changes to the configuration in Org 2 that should be pullable? On a first read, this sounds like expected behavior, so I'm not sure how to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi @DavidReed, both the scratch org have different DX projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Salesforce DX, the source of truth is always the version control repository (your local work directory). It sounds like you have a setup like this:

```
sfdx-project-1/ 
     force-app/
         (your source code lives here)
     --> Link to Scratch Org 1
     --> Link to Scratch Org 2

sfdx-project-2/ 
     force-app/
         (empty)
     --> Link to Scratch Org 2
```

You populated Scratch Org 2 from Scratch Org 1, and now you're trying to pull that data back down from Scratch Org 2 into `sfdx-project-2`.

Here's the thing: you *probably* don't need to do this, because `sfdx-project-1` is really the source of truth for your project. You could simply do something like (assuming you're using something with a POSIX-y command line):

```
cp -R sfdx-project-1/force-app/* sfdx-project-2/force-app/
```

or

```
git clone sfdx-project-1 sfdx-project-2
```

to copy all of your file content *locally*. Your projects should both match up with both scratch orgs at that time.

I suspect sfdx is confused because you're going in some way the "wrong" direction by pulling a complete source set from the scratch org (*not* the source of truth) into a version control repository that's empty (the source of truth shouldn't be empty).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. The reason why I am doing this is I have developed my functionality in ScratchOrg1 and I want to test my functionality in ScratchOrg2 as Salesforce recommend using two different scratch org for both development and testing. So, I have pushed all my data from ScratchOrg1 to ScratchOrg2. Am I doing it right or there is a better approach for this?

Comment: Can you link to that recommendation? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me apropos of nothing.